Need to upsert vectors in pinecone DB in Next JS
So I need help pushing vectors into the db, currently something is wrong with the await function here, I am getting an error.
Here is my code for the pinecone.ts file that uploads to the db:
import {
  Index,
  Pinecone,
  PineconeRecord,
  RecordMetadata,
} from "@pinecone-database/pinecone";
import { downloadFromS3 } from "./s3.server";
import { PDFLoader } from "@langchain/community/document_loaders/fs/pdf";
import {
  Document,
  RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter,
} from "@pinecone-database/doc-splitter";
import { getEmbeddings } from "./embeddings";
import { Vector } from "@pinecone-database/pinecone/dist/pinecone-generated-ts-fetch";
import md5 from "md5";
import { convertToAscii } from "./utils";

let pinecone: Pinecone | null = null;
const api = process.env.PINECONE_API_KEY || "";

export const getPineconeClient = () => {
  if (!pinecone) {
    pinecone = new Pinecone({
      apiKey: api,
    });
  }
  return pinecone;
};

type PDFPage = {
  pageContent: string;
  metadata: {
    loc: { pageNumber: number };
  };
};

export async function loadS3IntoPinecone(fileKey: string) {
  try {
    // 1. Obtain the PDF
    console.log("Downloading PDF from S3...");
    const file_name = await downloadFromS3(fileKey);

    if (!file_name) {
      throw new Error("File not found");
    }

    // 2. Download and read PDF
    console.log("Reading PDF...");
    const loader = new PDFLoader(file_name as string);
    const pages = (await loader.load()) as PDFPage[];

    // 3. Split and segment the PDF
    console.log("Splitting PDF...");
    const documents = await Promise.all(pages.map(prepareDocument));

    // 4. Vectorize and embed individual docs
    console.log("Embedding documents...");
    const vectors = await Promise.all(documents.flat().map(embedDocument));

    // 5. Upload to Pinecone
    const client = await getPineconeClient();
    const pineconeIndex = client.Index("teachtalk");

    console.log("inserting vectors into pinecone");
    
    
    const namespace = convertToAscii(fileKey);

    // Push vectors to Pinecone index
    await pineconeIndex.upsert({
      vectors: vectors as PineconeRecord<RecordMetadata>[],
      namespace: namespace,
    });

    console.log("Upload complete");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in loadS3IntoPinecone", error);
  }
}

async function embedDocument(doc: Document): Promise<Vector> {
  try {
    const embeddings = await getEmbeddings(doc.pageContent);
    const hash = md5(doc.pageContent);

    return {
      id: hash,
      values: embeddings,
      metadata: {
        text: doc.metadata.text,
        pageNumber: doc.metadata.pageNumber,
      },
    } as PineconeRecord;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in embedding document", error);
    throw error;  // Ensure errors are propagated
  }
}

// Converts to bytes then to a string
export const truncateStringByBytes = (str: string, bytes: number) => {
  const enc = new TextEncoder();
  return new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(enc.encode(str).slice(0, bytes));
};

async function prepareDocument(page: PDFPage): Promise<Document[]> {
  let { pageContent, metadata } = page;

  // Replace empty line with space
  pageContent = pageContent.replace(/\n/g, "");

  // Split the docs
  const splitter = new RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter();
  const docs = await splitter.splitDocuments([
    new Document({
      pageContent,
      metadata: {
        pageNumber: metadata.loc.pageNumber,
        text: truncateStringByBytes(pageContent, 36000),
      },
    }),
  ]);

  return docs;
}

This is the error I'm getting right now:
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'vectors' does not exist in type                       'PineconeRecord<RecordMetadata>[]'.

I tried basically everything from gpt to docs, I can't find how to properly upsert the vectors into the db in batched, would grately appreciate the help

What version of pinecone are you using? The closest API I found was Pinecone.index.namespace.upsert and it takes an Array as argument.

i'm using the latest version

I’m surprised that’s the only error you are getting. See how it is done in the docs.
